# IBM Cloud Code Engine: How to setup maintenance domain when backup going on

Tags: ibm-cloud, maintenance-mode, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I want to show web application is under maintenance while the backup activity goin on. so user can't access the application till that time. In code engine it is possible or we need to do changes in code.

Code engine provide any check for maintenance window so if flag true then user can see the maintenance window.

Answer (score 2):

There are different options on how to deal with that situation in cloud deployments.

- The easiest and most reliable probably is to use the [IBM Cloud Internet Services (CIS) with the Forwarding URL](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cis?topic=cis-manage-your-ibm-cloud-internet-services-deployment-for-optimal-reliability#forwarding-url) configuration. You can set up a rule on when to serve from a different site, e.g., when one fails or is unavailable.
- You could also use [domain mapping with Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-domain-mappings) and reconfigure it to a different deployment.